# nodejs open multiple html files doesn't work

Tags: node.js

I've tried a few different npm packages that open files and I have the same issue with all of them.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/opn
https://www.npmjs.com/package/open

the problem: I am not able to open multiple html files on my hard drive at once. but when I try to open just one of them it works fine. any idea what's causing this issue?

This DOESN'T work (the web pages don't open in my browser):

```
var fs = require('fs');
var opn = require('opn');

fs.writeFile('open.html', 'hello');
fs.writeFile('open1.html', 'hello1');
fs.writeFile('open2.html', 'hello2');
fs.writeFile('open3.html', 'hello3');
fs.writeFile('open4.html', 'hello4');
fs.writeFile('open5.html', 'hello5');

console.log('files created');

opn('open.html');
opn('open1.html');
opn('open2.html');
opn('open3.html');
opn('open4.html');
opn('open5.html');
```

BUT the code below WORKS (the one web page opens fine in my browser):

```
var fs = require('fs');
var opn = require('opn');

fs.writeFile('open.html', 'hello');

console.log('file created');

opn('open.html');
```

Comment: Perhaps it is by design that this is happening. Have you tried requiring `opn` separately for each file you want to open?

Comment: @BlazeSahlzen I tried adding a 'setTimeout(function() {}, 500);' around the multiple opns and it worked properly. perhaps fs.write can't create the file fast enough and there is no file for opn to open? Is there a way to skip the writing of the file and just have the html in a variable and open a website with that variable being the code? something like: var abc = 'my html code'; open('test.hml', abc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're aware of the side effects, you can use `fs.writeFileSync` instead of `fs.writeFile`: https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefilesync_file_data_options

`fs.writeFile`is asynchronous and will return immediately (even if the file is not created yet). You can use it with a callback if you want to wait for the operation to finish.

`fs.writeFileSync` blocks the main thread until the file is written, and returns only then. If you don't want to change your code too much, you can probably just use that.

Comment: thanks for clarifying. I was able to use fs.writeFile and use the callback to open the page. this works perfectly.